# How to query pivot table in Adonis Js

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I have a pivot table of `category_post` which contains the `post_id` and `category_id`
i also have
Post Model

```
categories(){

      return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Category')

    }
```

Category

```
posts(){

      return this.belongsToMany('App/Models/Post')

    }
```

i am trying to loop all the posts that belongs to a category when user visits this route `localhost:3333/category/news`

Answer (score 0):

You can use lucids whereHas to get all posts from specific category.

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_wherehas

```
const posts = await Post
  .query()
  .whereHas('category', (builder) => {
    builder.where('slug', 'news')
  })
  .fetch()
```

Or if you have already loaded category, you can also eagerLoad posts for it using:

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_eager_loading

```
const category = await Category.query().where('slug', 'news').firstOrFail()
const posts = await category.posts().fetch()
```

Check docs for .wherePivot also it could be useful to you too:
https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/relationships#_querying_pivot_table